# version control in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

Has any body implemented version control for salesforce based projects? If yes pleas. share as to how and what tools/technology used to implement the same. Mainly from github to Salesforce

Answer (score 2):

Use salesforce with github to enable version control for salesforce orgs.

These are the steps needs to follow for github integration(assuming that code is in salesforce org)

1. Install Force.com IDE and sync the salesforce code(https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation).
2. Open force.com IDE and create new force.com project to sync the code to eclipse( New --> Force.com project --> give salesforce credentials to sync the project from salesforce)
3. create a github repository and follow instructions to make salesforce code to github repository.
4. use **git push** command to push your code to github.

Answer (score 1):

I have used version control on multiple Salesforce implementations, but it is messy. I have used git and Apache Subversion, both work about the same except git is easier to use.

The process is pretty ugly. Developers code/configure in a development environment then check in code to a central branch (manually merge code). That branch is then deployed to a environment for testing, either manually or by a continuous integration process (Jenkins, etc.). New branches are created for new releases, not by developers.

Now on smaller projects (~<5 developers) I could see this working more traditionally, where the developer has his/her own branch for development then merges using git. With more developers the merging can get complex.

Once again this is not ideal and I have only really seen this done where version control is necessary due some industry compliance. I am really interested in a Salesforce version control tool, it is definitely something that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I believe this might help the community since Salesforce has changed a lot.

In our company, we are using Salesforce DX with Manifest, using some of DX's power but with legacy support. It gives us the ability to work with Orgs that are not using DX but still use DX's folder structure, and push/pull to the instance. Since the code is local, we can also version the code with git.

For this, we like to use Visual Studio Code, which has excellent extensions that make the work easier.

You need to:

1. Download visual studio code https://code.visualstudio.com/
2. Install Salesforce CLI https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm#sfdx_setup_install_cli
3. Back in VisualStudioCode open the extensions (Ctrl+Shift+X) and install “Salesforce Extension Pack”

Once you do this, you will have all you need to work with DX. The last step is actually to connect with your instance and download the code.

You need to:

1. In VSCode click View->Command Palette
2. Type ">SFDX: Create Project with Manifest" and hit enter
3. enter the project name and then select the folder where you want the project to be saved
4. Open "sfdx-project.json" and change "sfdcLoginUrl" to "https://test.salesforce.com", or leave it as is for Production (not recommended)
5. Open the command palette and type ">SFDX: Authorize an Org" hit enter
6. In the next option select "Project Default"
7. Enter an alias for the org and hit enter
8. A browser window will open, you will need to login to your developer sandbox there. And select allow access, once logged you can close the browser window
9. If you run sfdx "force:org:list" in the console, you should see the org as connected, and with a (U) next to the alias, that means it is the default org, and all commands will be done on that org.

**Adding git to the project**

1. In the root folder of the project type git init
2. Then git remote add origin "URL of the repository"
3. Git fetch origin
4. Next, we need to configure with the metadata we want to download, so open manifest/package.xml and add the objects you want to sync. Generally, the ones by default are ok, but if not, you can add more.

And there you have it. Now you can change code locally, push to git, and push to your instance.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We are using TFS right now. (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25125) All check-in's are made throw Eclipse(with force.com IDE plugin). It is not very cool, but it is working. But branching in TFS is quite poor, you are not able to track local changes immediately and you do not have your own local copy.

What I would recommend for you - use Git as a version control + bitbucket + bamboo as a build server. It is awesome solution not for only version control, but for whole continuos integration process, especially if you are using feature branches for developers. It is easy to merge / maintain and it has awesome UI for approve/build processes. We used SourceTree client when we used this configuration and everybody liked very much)

https://bitbucket.org
https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo

If you are working by Scrum with Jira you will like it even more - everything is 'bolt-on' integrated. In my opinion it is one of the best solutions for SFDC based projects, especially when you need to handle suck tricky stuff as undeploy/test execution(apex, protractor/selenium where needed, some JS unit tests).

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested to know that Salesforce is about to release a native, out-of-the-box, Version Control System in an upcoming release. This is part of a massive revamp of the change management capability planned through several releases. You may want to contact your salesforce account/partner manager as Beta enrolments have started. FYI...

Answer (score 0):

Yes by using bitbucket we have implemented version control . We create branches from the master repository . Every developer has their own sandbox . Each branch has been developed in respective sandbox . After completion we merge back each branches to master.

Answer (score 0):

We chose Flosum out of two other solutions due to the rollback feature, data migration functionality, and UI is well thought out and saved our team hours each day by cutting down the time to sort through poor code merge conflict nightmares when dealing with deploying and preventing overwrites when merging with the release branch. Also tells who does all changes and has in house ide to deal with the diff's of all components including dependencies within salesforce. I found this from when we did SWOT analysis of them and Capado.

[image: release management]

Flosum Overview
Innovative products for Salesforce - We created Flosum after a founder, who is an ex-Salesforce employee, recognized that cross-platform devops tools were not quite right for the Salesforce environment.  Most tools aren't designed for the unique architecture and different type of developer that you find on the Salesforce platform.  To that end, Flosum offers a fully-funtional version control and release management solution that also integrates with leading DevOps tools including Git, requirements management, testing, etc.

Release Management
Native version control system (and optional integration with Git) for Salesforce development and customization that includes environment management, code merge and conflict resolution, quality gates, release scheduling and automation, as well as capabilities to support governance, compliance, and audit.

[image: PipelineView]

Data Migration
Native data migration and management system for Salesforce that transfers data from one org/sandbox to another, with optional filtering and masking of data elements, while keeping hierarchical data relationships intact

Data Backup & Recovery
With the retirement of Salesforce’s Data Recovery Service July 2020, Flosum will offer backup and recovery services with options that are 100% Salesforce native or stored outside of the Salesforce

Strong and loyal customer base - The market appreciates Flosum’s innovation.  Our net customer retention is over 100% (growth outpaces churn within existing customers) and on the Salesforce AppExchange you’ll see over 250 reviews, three times as many reviews as the next closest competitor, and about 99% that are 5 stars.

Flosum has been deployed at some of the largest enterprises as well as small organizations with less mature devops processes and knowledge.  Flosum is particularly well-adopted in industries requiring a high degree of security, governance, and compliance, including healthcare and life sciences, financial services, and US federal government agencies.

Alignment with Salesforce -  Flosum is aligned with key platform and product teams at Salesforce, holding regular reviews for go-to-market strategy and product roadmap.  We support DX principles and product functionality and have a structured concurrent release strategy with Salesforce.

Responsibly run business - Flosum was founded in 2014